# Move a Git commit retrospectively to another branch in the history

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I accidentally committed a general change on a development branch and already merged it to the `master` branch a while ago:

```
* HEAD
* ...
*
* 2c884bc Updated Gradle Root Project Name
*   4926f6a Merge branch 'wip-dev-Logger'
|\
| * 43161fb Revised Logger
| * 13c8303 Switched to JDA 4.4.0_351
* | 599c72e Added Answerer interface
|/
* 4b0dcb8 Switched to Java 17
*
* ...
*
```

Is it possible to move commit `13c8303` from the development to the master branch without destroying the merge/branch history?

It should then look like this:

```
* HEAD
* ...
*
* 2c884bc Updated Gradle Root Project Name
*   4926f6a Merge branch 'wip-dev-Logger'
|\
| * 43161fb Revised Logger
* | 13c8303 Switched to JDA 4.4.0_351
* | 599c72e Added Answerer interface
|/
* 4b0dcb8 Switched to Java 17
*
* ...
*
```

Comment: It's possible to construct a new history, but all new commits will have different hashes than before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer from @IMSop, I came up with the follwoing solution:

1. In my case there were no other branches apart from `master` and I have not yet pushed any of my mistakes on a remote

**If you have an unmerged branch pointing to a newer commit, make sure you know how to handle the additional difficulties to come.**

2. `git rebase --root --interactive --rebase-merges`
3. Change the order of commits in the editor

```
...

pick 4b0dcb8 Switched to Java 17
label branch-point
pick 13c8303 Switched to JDA 4.4.0_351                       <--- COMMIT TO MOVE ---
pick 43161fb Revised Logger
label wip-dev-Logger
reset branch-point # Switched to Java 17
pick 599c72e Added Answerer interface
merge -C 4926f6a wip-dev-Logger # Merge branch 'wip-dev-Logger'
pick 2c884bc Updated Gradle Root Project Name

...
```

to

```
pick 4b0dcb8 Switched to Java 17
label branch-point
pick 43161fb Revised Logger
label wip-dev-Logger
reset branch-point # Switched to Java 17
pick 599c72e Added Answerer interface
pick 13c8303 Switched to JDA 4.4.0_351                       <--- COMMIT TO MOVE ---
merge -C 4926f6a wip-dev-Logger # Merge branch 'wip-dev-Logger'
pick 2c884bc Updated Gradle Root Project Name

...
```

4. Save and close the editor. Everything should work fine if you didn't touch any files in the moved commit that could conflict with this merge.
5. Confirm using `git log --graph --oneline`:

```
* HEAD
* ...
*
* c5d2985 Updated Gradle Root Project Name
*   31a26e4 Merge branch 'wip-dev-Logger'
|\
| * 13e0a2c Revised Logger
* | 5cebef6 Switched to JDA 4.4.0_351
* | 599c72e Added Answerer interface
|/
* 4b0dcb8 Switched to Java 17
*
* ...
*
```

Answer (score 2):

Individual commits in git are *immutable*, because they are identified by a hash of:

- The entire code tree
- The commit message, date, and authorship information
- The hash identifying their parent, or multiple parents in the case of a merge commit

Meanwhile, *branches* can be changed at will, because they are simply a movable pointer to a particular commit.

So the outcome you have shown is impossible, because if the commit identified by hash `13c8303` had a different parent, it would have a different hash. The commits identified by `43161fb` and `4926f6a` would also have different parents, so different hashed - and so on for all commits "forwards" from the point in history you want to create.

It is possible to create that alternative history, using the [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) command, but *every working copy, and every branch* after the change you make will need to be updated to refer to the new history. If you get it right, it will look something like this:

```
* HEAD
* ...
*
* 56fa78b Updated Gradle Root Project Name
* 12cd34e Merge branch 'wip-dev-Logger'
|\
| * ef78ab9 Revised Logger
* | 12ab34d Switched to JDA 4.4.0_351
* | 599c72e Added Answerer interface
|/
* 4b0dcb8 Switched to Java 17
*
* ...
*
```

If you try to use a branch from later in the original history without rebasing it onto the new history, you'll end up with two versions of all the commits after the ones you change - and probably a lot of conflicts when you try to merge them back together.

Comment: I know about the commits having different hashes (I just copied the graph to show what I mean) after such rebase and in my case that would be fine, because I'm the only one who worked on this project for a long time and haven't pushed it yet. Neither I have added or merged more branches which would conflict. (In additon there shouldn't be any merge conflicts at all because in the commit I want to move, I edited completely spearate files.) What exactely am I supposed to do in a rebase to change branches / parents afterwards?

Comment: @Gumbini Basically, you just keep rebasing each branch on top of the last one, until you've recreated all the commits you need.